# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.c8y_Event_MSG' [deserializeJSON]

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have my main method `static async Task Main(string[] args)` and another async method `public static async Task c8y_pushEvent(string Event_MSG)` inside my `class Program`. I'm trying to call the `public static async Task c8y_pushEvent(string Event_MSG)` from inside `static async Task Main(string[] args)`.

```
class Program
{
    int int_lastPushedId = 235;
    int get_maxID_old = 250;
    string c8y_Event_MSG = String.Empty;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Here's where I am getting the problem.
        for(int event_dbID_lp = int_lastPushedId + 1 ; event_dbID_lp <= get_maxID_old ; event_dbID_lp++)
                {
                SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand(queryString4, connection);
                command4.Parameters.Add("@ID", (int)event_dbID_lp);
                SqlDataReader reader4 = command4.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader4.Read())
                    {
                        c8y_Event_MSG = Convert.ToString(reader4[0]);
                        await c8y_pushEvent(c8y_Event_MSG);
                    }
                    reader4.Close();
                }
     }

     public static async Task c8y_pushEvent(string Event_MSG)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
        var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        var httpClientFactory = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

        List<KeyValue> keyvalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValue>>(Event_MSG);
        string controllerName = keyvalue[0].ToString();
        JArray EventMSG = JArray.Parse(Event_MSG);
        var item = EventMSG[0];

        var httpClientgetControllerId = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("getControllerId");
        var httpClientcreateGolfControllerEvent = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("createGolfControllerEvent");

        var request1 = await httpClientgetControllerId.GetAsync($"abc/xyz/{controllerName}");
        if (request1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage request2 = await httpClientcreateGolfControllerEvent.PostAsync("event/events", stringContent);
            //stringContent is fetched from some other lines which I've not 
            //included here
        }
     }

     private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddHttpClient("getControllerId", options =>
        {
            options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.com/");

            options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic","auth_value");
        });

        services.AddHttpClient("createGolfControllerEvent", options =>
        {
            options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.com/");
            options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic","auth_value");
            options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.com.nsn.xyz.event+json");
        });
     }

     public class KeyValue
    {
        [JsonProperty("ControllerName")]
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format(ControllerName.ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.c8y_Event_MSG' [deserializeJSON]

on line

```
await c8y_pushEvent(c8y_Event_MSG);
```

How can I fix this issue?

**Additional question:**

The difference between `int_lastPushedId` and `get_maxID_old` can be as big as 1000+
hence there can be 1000+ iterations.
Is my implementation of IHttpClientFactory suitable for this, making sure there's no exhaustion of socket/ports?

Comment: if `c8y_Event_MSG` ment to be a temporary variable than you could add `var` before the name, so: `var c8y_Event_MSG = ....`

Comment: @PaulSinnema I'm sorry I've not included the entire code here, but ```c8y_Event_MSG``` is also declared as ```string c8y_Event_MSG = String.Empty;``` Let me edit it to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Add `static` in front of the `string` declaration.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Well, the error is gone. Thanks for that. I've a question though. I get value inside ```c8y_Event_MSG``` from database which I then pass as an argument to the ```c8y_pushEvent``` method. Declaring it as static won't affect any flow, right? ```c8y_Event_MSG = Convert.ToString(reader4[0]);``` this is the first instance of the variable being assigned a value.

Comment: Do you need to remember the string? If not I would use the `var` instead of declaring it `static`. No, I don't think it will have an effect in both cases (`static` or `var`).

Comment: @PaulSinnema That'll be fine in my case then, Thanks again. Any suggestions on my additional question?

Comment: Your additional question is very different to the main question, please ask the additional question separately.

Comment: ...but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the factories. You can have a single `static HttpClient httpClient` make all these requests. `new ServiceCollection();` in a for loop is definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main error

It looks like `c8y_Event_MSG` should be local:

```
while (reader4.Read())
{
     var c8y_Event_MSG = Convert.ToString(reader4[0]);
     await c8y_pushEvent(c8y_Event_MSG);
}
```

## HttpClient qestion

All of the Dependency Injection code seem unnecessary. I cannot think of a situation where `var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();` in a for loop
would be a good idea.

Here's a simpler version that should do the job:

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient httpClient;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
       httpClient = new HttpClient();

       //Setup auth and base address 

       for(...)
       {
          ...
          c8y_pushEvent(...)
       }
    } 

    public static async Task c8y_pushEvent(string Event_MSG, HttpClient)
    {
        List<KeyValue> keyvalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValue>>(Event_MSG);
        string controllerName = keyvalue[0].ToString();
        JArray EventMSG = JArray.Parse(Event_MSG);
        var item = EventMSG[0];

        var request1 = await httpClient.GetAsync($"abc/xyz/{controllerName}");
     }
```

Comment: Actually I have to make two requets ```GetAsync``` and then a ```PostAsync``` inside my ```public static async Task c8y_pushEvent(string Event_MSG)```. I read somewhere factories are better than HttpClient as the later can cause socket/port exhaustion. I do agree that ```new ServiceCollection();``` inside for loop looks like a bad idea as we are not resusing but creating a new instance everytime.

Comment: I've updated the sample code. Basically I want all the get and post requests to complete in a sequence. Can you explain your solution keeping this scenario in context : ```Suppose For loop runs for 800 iterations. Each execution of the for loop must continue only after the current execution has completed it's Post request.``` Will your solution have no risk of socket/port exhaustion? Also can I use same httpClient for both Get and Post request? Notice I've to add an extra header while initializing services for my Post request.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can reuse HttpClient for all http verbs (GET, POST, PUT, etc). 
2. You can `await httpClient.GetAsync` -> await httpClient.PostAsync -> await httpClient.GetAsync in an infinite loop and it will not exhaust the sockets. (and having a single httpClient helps not running out of sockets). (BTW. Because you're doing it in a sequence even if you create+dispose on every request you should be fine as well)

Comment: Just one more question. This Program is scheduled to run every 5 mins. The sockets/ports which will be opened during the requests, will they get disposed itself?